# Angular Promise Promise Decorator get Resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get a message when the promise resolve is completed

```
$provide.decorator('$q', function ($delegate) {
    var defer = $delegate.defer;
    $delegate.defer = function () {
        var deferred = defer();
        console.log("defer");
        return deferred;
    };
    $delegate.resolve = function () {
        var resolved = resolve();
        console.log("resolve");
        return deferred;
    };
    return $delegate;
});
```

Comment: `resolve` is not a method of `$q`, but method of deferred object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is completely correct, but for imagination, it would look something like this

```
$provide.decorator('$q', function ($delegate) {
    var defer = $delegate.defer;
    $delegate.defer = function () {
        var deferred = defer(),
            resolve = deferred.resolve;

        deferred.resolve = function(data) {
            console.log('resolved');
            return resolve(data);
        };

        return deferred;
    };
    return $delegate;
});
```